# VIM highlight unique words in buffer?

Tags: vim, highlighting

When using vim for programming any unique words in file/buffer is quite likely to be a typo(of ether variable name, method name or a language construct). Thus it would be quite a nice way to catch such typos with the ability to highlight any unique words in file, without any fancy language analysis or parsing or the need to even know what programming language is being used. Of course it would be best for that to happen as you type so that you could see your typos immediately. Somehow I don't thing I'm the first one to come up with such an idea, so maybe someone has such setup or has any suggestions?

Comment: I feel like this would be a hell of a strain on the eyes. Have you taken a look at [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html), or using a linter? (For example, [pflakes](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim) will highlight/underline a variable that doesn't exist for Python code).

Comment: Maybe, You're the first one to come up with such an idea. :)

Comment: I do not think that it would be strain, since source code almost always have most of words repeated more than once, well at least for sizable files.

Comment: Sure, but if your goal is to spot undefined words, I think you have the wrong approach. There are loads of tools out there to highlight undefined words.

Answer (score 2):

Creative idea.

I did some quick prototyping with this Vimscript snippet:

```
let stat = {}
for ii in range(1, line('$'))
    for word in split(getline(ii), '\(\k\@!.\)\+')
        let stat[word] = get(stat, word, 0) + 1
    endfor
endfor
echo sort(keys(filter(copy(stat), 'v:val == 1')))
```

Running that on $VIM/vim73/autoload/vimball.vim (a 23.2 k file with 737 lines), I get the following single keyword occurrences:

```
12, 1502, 2004, 2009, 2010, 299, 31, 4, 702, Allow, Apr, At, Author,
AutoInstall, Constants, Copyright, Date, DechoTabOn, ENTER, Error,
Functions, GetLatestVimScripts, Input, LICENSE, Listing, Load, Modelines,
No, Normal, Once, Output, Own, Ph, Risk, Statement, Usage, Use, VIM,
Version, Vim, Windoze, Your, about, accomplished, actions, allow, already,
appear, appears, applies, apportion, assume, attempts, automatically, base,
based, bash, both, bypass, c, ch, change, construct, continue, copyright,
cp, cr, create, creates, cygwin, decompress, decompression, defined, did,
dir, distribute, does, doesn, embedded, enc, endfor, even, events,
evidence, except, existing, express, extraction, fmr, fo, force, function,
getpos, give, given, grab, ie, implied, included, index, initialize, input,
inputrestore, inputsave, insure, invoked, its, just, keep, keepcpo, list,
listing, loop, made, messages, missing, mkvimball, named, neither, next,
noacd, nofile, noma, nor, normal, noruler, noshowcmd, ok, older, on,
option, options, over, patch, pick, picked, placed, present, previous,
prologue, prompt, read, readable, redraw, removed, same, see, setpos,
setting, settings, shell, showing, skip, specified, specify, spite, split,
standard, string, strlen, sure, suspect, switch, ta, tab#, take, that,
title, true, un, undefined, under, used, v31, various, warning, warranty,
was, when, where, will, wrote, your, zsh
```

Hm, doesn't look very useful to me (it also doesn't get much better when comments are excluded), but maybe you can take this and improve upon it.